# aggregating data to getting running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which outputs the below

[image]

I need to get it to provide a running total so for March it would give whats been paid in Feb and Mar, then for April Feb,Mar & Apr and so on.

Never come across needing this kind of aggregation before in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  [monthid], 
  [month], 
  ( select sum([paid]) from tbl t2 where t2.[monthid] <= t1.[monthid] ) as paid
from tbl t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/13744550#13744550) on it. Turns out that recursive common table expression is the fastest method to get running total in SQL Server < 2012.

So in your case it could be something like:

```
with cte as
(
    select T.MonthID, T.Month, T.Paid, T.Paid as Running_Paid
    from Table1 as T
    where T.MonthID = 118
    union all
    select T.MonthID, T.Month, T.Paid, T.Paid + C.Running_Paid as Running_Paid
    from cte as C
        inner join Table1 as T on T.MonthID = C.MonthID + 1
)
select *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     T.MonthId
    ,T.[Month]
    ,T.Value
    ,RT.runningTotal
from Table_Name T
             CROSS APPLY 
                        (
                          SELECT SUM(value) as runningTotal
                          FROM Table_Name
                          WHERE MonthId <= T.MonthId
                        ) as RT
order by T.MonthId
```

**Test Data**

```
declare @t1 TABLE (Monthid int, month varchar(10), Value decimal(18,2))

insert into @t1
values 
 (1,'JAN-13',35.00)
,(2, 'FEB-13',35.00) 
,(3,'MAR-13',35.00)
,(4,'APR-13',35.00)
,(5,'JUN-13',35.00)
,(6,'Jul-13',35.00)
,(7,'Aug-13',35.00)

SELECT
     T.MonthId
    ,T.[Month]
    ,T.Value
    ,RT.runningTotal
from @t1 T
             CROSS APPLY 
                        (
                          SELECT SUM(value) as runningTotal
                          FROM @t1
                          WHERE MonthId <= T.MonthId
                        ) as RT
order by T.MonthId
```

**RESULTS**

```
MonthId Month   Value   runningTotal
1       JAN-13  35.00   35.00
2       FEB-13  35.00   70.00
3       MAR-13  35.00   105.00
4       APR-13  35.00   140.00
5       JUN-13  35.00   175.00
6       Jul-13  35.00   210.00
7       Aug-13  35.00   245.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Running totals in 2008 are kind of a pain.  SQL Fiddle seems to have gone MIA again, but here's a simplistic example of how you can do it.

declare @t1 TABLE
(monthid int,
mth  varchar(10),
paid decimal(18,2),
running_paid decimal(18,2))

```
insert into @t1
values (1,'JAN-13',35.00,0)
,(2, 'FEB-13',35.00,0) 
,(3,'MAR-13',35.00,0)


declare @running decimal(18,2)
set @running= 0
update @t1 set running_paid = @running, @running= @running+ paid 

select
*
from
@t1
```

Which will give you:

```
ID  MTH     PAID    RUNNING_PAID
1   JAN-13  35.00   35.00
2   FEB-13  35.00   70.00
3   MAR-13  35.00   105.00
```

EDIT:
As  Bogdan Sahlean points out, this is a very funky little process.  You could also use a cursor:

```
declare @t1 TABLE
(monthid int,
mth  varchar(10),
paid decimal(18,2)
)

insert into @t1
values (1,'JAN-13',35.00)
,(2, 'FEB-13',35.00) 
,(3,'MAR-13',35.00)


declare @running table
(monthid int,
mth  varchar(10),
paid decimal(18,2),
running_paid decimal(18,2))


declare c cursor
for select monthid,mth,paid from @t1
open c
declare @Id int
declare @Mth varchar(10)
declare @paid decimal(18,2)
declare @Running_Total decimal(18,2)
set @Running_Total = 0
fetch next from c
    into @Id,@Mth,@paid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        fetch next from c
            into @Id,@Mth,@paid
        select @Running_Total = @Running_Total + @paid  --Here's this version's hack for running total
        insert into @running values (@Id,@Mth,@paid,@Running_Total) 
    end

select
*
from
@running
```

They all kind of stink. This is a lot easier in SQL 2012.

Comment: While the `quirky update` method is fastest method it has a lot of restrictions. You should publish the links to sqlservercentral.com articles on this subject.